# XSLT 2.0 3.0 for-each context error when tokenizing attributes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, tokenize

Given this XML

```
<dmodule>   
      <content>     
            <warningsAndCautionsRef>
                  <warningRef id="w001" warningIdentNumber="warning-001">
                  </warningRef>
                  <warningRef id="w002" warningIdentNumber="warning-002">
                  </warningRef>
                  <cautionRef id="c001" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001">
                  </cautionRef>
                  <cautionRef id="c002" cautionIdentNumber="caution-002">
                  </cautionRef>
            </warningsAndCautionsRef>
            <faultReporting>
                  <preliminaryRqmts>
                        <reqSafety>
                              <safetyRqmts cautionRefs="c001 c002" warningRefs="w001 w002"/>
                        </reqSafety>
                  </preliminaryRqmts>
            </faultReporting>
      </content>
</dmodule>
```

I would like to tokenize the attributes `@cautionRefs` (and `@warningRefs`) and then find the `cautionRef` element that matches its `@id` to the tokenized value:

```
<xsl:template match="@cautionRefs">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\s')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id=.]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but the apply-templates fails: Fatal error during transformation Leading '/' selects nothing: the context item is not a node. It works if I don't tokenize and use string functions instead but that is not desirable.

Desired  result:
Tokenize `@cautionRefs="c001 c002"` (which has multiple parent elements)

So each value is passed to the `<cautionRef>`template that will retrieve the caution and warning statements, to be displayed in a PDF:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id='c001']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id='c002']"/>
```

I tried using `<xsl:key name="id" match="*" use="@id"/>` with

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('id',tokenize(.,'\s'))">
```

but the `for-each` is blank.

The above apply-templates will match with this `<cautionRef>` template, which retrieves the caution and warning statements correctly. I just need help with the context of the `@cautionRefs` template:

```
<xsl:template match="cautionRef">
    <xsl:variable name="IdentNumber" select="@cautionIdentNumber"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//cautionSpec[cautionIdent/@cautionIdentNumber=$IdentNumber]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: Please add the expected result too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full working example. NB it's best to have this level of detail in the actual question; i.e. a sample input file, the XSLT, and output, along with an example of what you *want* the output to look like.

Input:

```xml
<test>
  <safetyRqmts cautionRefs="c001 c002" warningRefs="w001"/>
  <cautionRef id="c001" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001"/>
  <cautionRef id="c002" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001"/>
</test>
```

Stylesheet:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="by_id" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="@cautionRefs|@warningRefs">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by_id', tokenize(.))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```xml
<test>
  <safetyRqmts><cautionRef id="c001" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001"/><cautionRef id="c002" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001"/></safetyRqmts>
  <cautionRef id="c001" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001"/>
  <cautionRef id="c002" cautionIdentNumber="caution-001"/>
</test>
```

Comment: I believe the simple solution would be to use `key('by_id', tokenize(.,'\s'))`. Then there would be no problem of getting back to the context of the input XML document. However, I do not see the entire picture, so this is mainly guessing (as I suspect are both answers given above).

Comment: You're right; the second parameter to the `key()` function is a sequence, so the sequence of tokens could simply be passed directly, without the need for a `for-each` loop (which does work, by the way; it's not a guess).

Comment: I am sure it works in your scenario - but OP's scenario is unknown. You may have noticed that OP tried this option but did not get the expected result.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the OP is actually doing because they didn't post a reproducible example; only snippets. But the point of this answer is to show that this _does_ work. You know what? I'm going to edit this answer once more and paste a full working stylesheet.

Comment: *"It's hard to tell what the OP is actually doing"* Exactly. Which is why I did not post an answer.

Comment: Brilliant. I am not sure why this answer retrieved the caution and warning statements, and not Daniel's solution, because they both were passing the tokenized values as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable and use that for context:

```xml
<xsl:template match="@cautionRefs|@warningRefs">
    <xsl:variable name="ctx" select="/"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\s')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$ctx//*[@id=.]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but I would use a `key` like you hinted at (updated to include context based on comments)...

```xml
<xsl:key name="by_id" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

<xsl:template match="@cautionRefs|@warningRefs">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\s')">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by_id',.,$root)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I concur about using the `key()` function. It's worth noting that the `id()` function will only match nodes which have the "ID" type. Having an attribute called `id` is not enough; you need a schema and you need your XML parser to have used the schema when parsing the file, otherwise it won't know that the attribute is a unique identifier. The exception is the `xml:id` attribute which is guaranteed to be an id even if you have no schema.

Comment: @ConalTuohy - good point about `id()` but I didn’t use that function.

Comment: Sure, I didn't mean to imply that. Just wanted to point out that `key()` is often worth using even when `id()` looks like it would be more specifically appropriate.

Comment: @ConalTuohy - Ahh I see now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Incidentally, your second suggestion (with `key()`) does have an error, I believe, because the `key()` function has effectively the same requirement as `xsl:apply-templates`; it needs a context node. So you'd need to use a variable to retain a context node, and pass it as the third parameter to `key()`. I will add an answer.

Comment: @ConalTuohy - nice catch! That’s the problem with questions without minimal reproducible examples; makes it harder to test.

Comment: I am grateful and thankful to everyone for their contributions, I apologize for my lackadaisical question-asking. @Daniel, this fixed the error, but for some reason the cautions and warnings were not being retrieved. This answer was helpful for me.

Comment: @Caroline - You're very welcome. It's nice to see some S1000D in an SO question.